# Why am I getting 'HiveError: Box not found' when trying to open a box on start up?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I had an app with Hive integrated perfectly. I decided to change the file names to make things more clear, and then I started getting this error.

I ended up rebuilding the app from scratch (copy-pasting the old code into a new project and directory files), and now I am getting the error once again.

The boxes in this project have not been created before, so I'm not sure how I am getting this error. How can I open the box if it won't let me open the box?

Here is the code as of now:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  final Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(appDocDir.path);

  Hive.registerAdapter(SettingAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(StudentAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(LessonAdapter());
  Hive.registerAdapter(ReportAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Student>('student_box');
  await Hive.openBox<Lesson>('lesson_box');
  await Hive.openBox<Report>('report_box');
  await Hive.openBox<Setting>('settings_box');

  if (Platform.isWindows || Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS) {
    DesktopWindow.setMinWindowSize(const Size(500, 700));
    //DesktopWindow.setMaxWindowSize(const Size(1000, 1000));
    DesktopWindow.setWindowSize(const Size(500, 700));
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Adding in the directory to the Hive initialization did not seem to change anything.

Here is an image of the error in action:

[image: image of the HiveError]

Comment: I don't see an register adapter for the Student class type

Comment: @Gwhyyy it's the second one, under the one for SettingAdapter